# Unicode RTMP URLs for use in JWPlayer & CloudFront

Tags: coldfusion, amazon-s3, jwplayer, amazon-cloudfront

I'm trying to figure out the correct way to encode a string here. On my cloudfront installation (i.e on my S3 Bucket), I have a folder with a special character:

> playlists/Medúlla/file.m4a

When trying to use this:

`playlist: [{file: "rtmp://MYCLOUDFRONTDISTRO/cfx/st/mp4:playlists/Medúlla/myfile.m4a"}],`

In a jwplayer playlist, how do I properly encode the playlist entry in jWPlayer? (Preferably in ColdFusion before it gets output). If I use `urlEncodedFormat()`, everything gets encoded. It's as though I *just* need to do something to the special chars, but I can't work out *what* (and how).

As a side note, everything works perfectly *Except* when I have a UTF8 char in this javascript config.

### UPDATE:

Narrowed this down: if I hardcode the HTML in, it works fine. If I save the playlist into a ColdFusion variable and output the variable in the JS configuration, it won't work.

Here's a console debug of JWPlayer when it works:

> JWPLAYERREADY ([PlayerEvent type="jwplayerReady" id="gwsPlayer"
>   client="FLASH WIN 11,5,502,149" version="6.2.3115" message="null"])
>
> JWPLAYERPLAYLISTLOADED ([PlaylistEvent type="jwplayerPlaylistLoaded"
>   index="0" id="gwsPlayer" client="FLASH WIN 11,5,502,149"
>   version="6.2.3115" message="null"])
>
> JWPLAYERPLAYLISTITEM ([PlaylistEvent type="jwplayerPlaylistItem"
>   index="0" id="gwsPlayer" client="FLASH WIN 11,5,502,149"
>   version="6.2.3115" message="null"])
>
> LOG (dispatching captions event of type: jwplayerCaptionsList)
>
> JWPLAYERCAPTIONSLIST ([CaptionsEvent type="jwplayerCaptionsList"
>   tracks="[object Object]" currentTrack="0" id="gwsPlayer" client="FLASH
>   WIN 11,5,502,149" version="6.2.3115"])
>
> LOAD (Loading PlaylistItem: [PlaylistItem
>   file=rtmp://MYCLOUDFRONTURL/cfx/st/mp4:playlists/Róisín
>   Murphy/Overpowered/10 Tell Everybody.m4a provider=rtmp level=0])
>
> JWPLAYERMEDIABEFOREPLAY ([MediaEvent type="jwplayerMediaBeforePlay"
>   id="gwsPlayer" client="FLASH WIN 11,5,502,149" version="6.2.3115"])
>
> JWPLAYERMEDIALEVELS ([MediaEvent type="jwplayerMediaLevels"
>   levels="[object Object]" currentQuality="0" id="gwsPlayer"
>   client="FLASH WIN 11,5,502,149" version="6.2.3115"])
>
> JWPLAYERMEDIALOADED ([MediaEvent type="jwplayerMediaLoaded"
>   id="gwsPlayer" client="FLASH WIN 11,5,502,149" version="6.2.3115"])
>
> JWPLAYERPLAYERSTATE ([PlayerStateEvent type="jwplayerPlayerState"
>   oldstate="IDLE" newstate="BUFFERING" id="gwsPlayer" client="FLASH WIN
>   11,5,502,149" version="6.2.3115" message="null"])
>
> JWPLAYERMEDIABUFFERFULL ([MediaEvent type="jwplayerMediaBufferFull"
>   id="gwsPlayer" client="FLASH WIN 11,5,502,149" version="6.2.3115"])
>
> JWPLAYERMEDIAMETA ([MediaEvent type="jwplayerMediaMeta"
>   screenwidth="0" transitioning="false" bufferfill="0" bandwidth="0"
>   qualitylevel="0" id="gwsPlayer" client="FLASH WIN 11,5,502,149"
>   version="6.2.3115"])
>
> JWPLAYERMEDIAMETA ([MediaEvent type="jwplayerMediaMeta"
>   audiochannels="2" audiosamplerate="44100" tags="" audiocodecid="mp4a"
>   type="metadata" trackinfo="[object Object]" duration="231.48"
>   aacaot="2" moovPosition="40" id="gwsPlayer" client="FLASH WIN
>   11,5,502,149" version="6.2.3115"])
>
> LOG (dispatching captions event of type: jwplayerCaptionsList)
>
> JWPLAYERCAPTIONSLIST ([CaptionsEvent type="jwplayerCaptionsList"
>   tracks="[object Object]" currentTrack="0" id="gwsPlayer" client="FLASH
>   WIN 11,5,502,149" version="6.2.3115"])
>
> JWPLAYERPLAYERSTATE ([PlayerStateEvent type="jwplayerPlayerState"
>   oldstate="BUFFERING" newstate="PLAYING" id="gwsPlayer" client="FLASH
>   WIN 11,5,502,149" version="6.2.3115" message="null"])
>
> JWPLAYERMEDIATIME ([MediaEvent type="jwplayerMediaTime"
>   duration="231.48" position="0" id="gwsPlayer" client="FLASH WIN
>   11,5,502,149" version="6.2.3115"])
>
> JWPLAYERMEDIAMETA ([MediaEvent type="jwplayerMediaMeta"
>   screenwidth="0" transitioning="false" bufferfill="1.5"
>   bandwidth="2037" qualitylevel="0" id="gwsPlayer" client="FLASH WIN
>   11,5,502,149" version="6.2.3115"])
>
> JWPLAYERMEDIATIME ([MediaEvent type="jwplayerMediaTime"
>   duration="231.48" position="0.1" id="gwsPlayer" client="FLASH WIN
>   11,5,502,149" version="6.2.3115"])
>
> JWPLAYERMEDIAMETA ([MediaEvent type="jwplayerMediaMeta"
>   screenwidth="0" transitioning="false" bufferfill="2" bandwidth="2037"
>   qualitylevel="0" id="gwsPlayer" client="FLASH WIN 11,5,502,149"
>   version="6.2.3115"])
>
> JWPLAYERMEDIATIME ([MediaEvent type="jwplayerMediaTime"
>   duration="231.48" position="0.3" id="gwsPlayer" client="FLASH WIN
>   11,5,502,149" version="6.2.3115"])
>   --snip--

And with *identical* HTML but output via CF

JWPLAYERREADY

> ([PlayerEvent type="jwplayerReady" id="gwsPlayer" client="FLASH WIN
>   11,5,502,149" version="6.2.3115" message="null"])
>
> JWPLAYERPLAYLISTLOADED ([PlaylistEvent type="jwplayerPlaylistLoaded"
>   index="0" id="gwsPlayer" client="FLASH WIN 11,5,502,149"
>   version="6.2.3115" message="null"])
>
> JWPLAYERPLAYLISTITEM ([PlaylistEvent type="jwplayerPlaylistItem"
>   index="0" id="gwsPlayer" client="FLASH WIN 11,5,502,149"
>   version="6.2.3115" message="null"])
>
> LOG (dispatching captions event of type: jwplayerCaptionsList)
>
> JWPLAYERCAPTIONSLIST ([CaptionsEvent type="jwplayerCaptionsList"
>   tracks="[object Object]" currentTrack="0" id="gwsPlayer" client="FLASH
>   WIN 11,5,502,149" version="6.2.3115"])
>
> LOAD (Loading PlaylistItem: [PlaylistItem
>   file=rtmp://MYCLOUDFRONTURL/cfx/st/mp4:playlists/Róisín
>   Murphy/Overpowered/10 Tell Everybody.m4a provider=rtmp level=0])
>
> JWPLAYERMEDIABEFOREPLAY ([MediaEvent type="jwplayerMediaBeforePlay"
>   id="gwsPlayer" client="FLASH WIN 11,5,502,149" version="6.2.3115"])
>
> JWPLAYERMEDIALEVELS ([MediaEvent type="jwplayerMediaLevels"
>   levels="[object Object]" currentQuality="0" id="gwsPlayer"
>   client="FLASH WIN 11,5,502,149" version="6.2.3115"])
>
> JWPLAYERMEDIALOADED ([MediaEvent type="jwplayerMediaLoaded"
>   id="gwsPlayer" client="FLASH WIN 11,5,502,149" version="6.2.3115"])
>
> JWPLAYERPLAYERSTATE ([PlayerStateEvent type="jwplayerPlayerState"
>   oldstate="IDLE" newstate="BUFFERING" id="gwsPlayer" client="FLASH WIN
>   11,5,502,149" version="6.2.3115" message="null"])
>
> JWPLAYERMEDIABUFFERFULL ([MediaEvent type="jwplayerMediaBufferFull"
>   id="gwsPlayer" client="FLASH WIN 11,5,502,149" version="6.2.3115"])
>
> JWPLAYERMEDIAMETA ([MediaEvent type="jwplayerMediaMeta"
>   transitioning="false" qualitylevel="0" screenwidth="0" bandwidth="0"
>   bufferfill="0" id="gwsPlayer" client="FLASH WIN 11,5,502,149"
>   version="6.2.3115"])
>
> JWPLAYERMEDIAMETA ([MediaEvent type="jwplayerMediaMeta"
>   transitioning="false" qualitylevel="0" screenwidth="0" bandwidth="0"
>   bufferfill="0" id="gwsPlayer" client="FLASH WIN 11,5,502,149"
>   version="6.2.3115"])

--snip--

Comment: [JW Player - Embedding with International Characters](http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/jw-player-for-flash-v5/16002/embedding-with-international-characters/). You should be able to use `urlEncodedFormat()` around the individual part(s) of the URL if you do not want the entire URL encoded.

Comment: Really strange - I have the playlist in a CF variable: if I don't output it using CF its fine: if I use CF, JW Player moves umlauts etc one character over (i.e Björk becomes Bjork (with Umlaut over the r).

Comment: More investigation required from my end!

Comment: If you are using the JW Embedder, you shouldn't need to URL Encode anything, actually.

Comment: I think it might be something to do with ColdFusion and cfsavecontent - if I hard code it, it works. If I attempt to save it in a variable and output it, something happens - the output is identical, but now (having updated to 6.02 jwplayer) it goes to infinite buffering. Will have to look into it!

Comment: Have you tried using <cfprocessingdirective ...> to force utf-8?

Comment: @Travis - yep, on both page the function is (cfWheels, so /events/functions.cfm) and the actual page.

Have also moved the function which creates the cfsavecontent block into the same page (so whole page wrapped) but same result.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found my own answer: I was concentrating too much on the output when I should have been looking more closely on how the data was being imported: turns out using CFFILE upload then read can cause all sorts of encoding issues. Fixed the issue by simply using a text field instead of a file upload, et voila, the encoding as stored in the database was fine. I was doing all my tests with tainted data. *sigh*.

Lesson learned, moving on... :)